# router.query not updated after router.push in next/router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have an issue I need to get query params after they are updated.

In this example when I make the `console.log` the `router.query` is reset to an empty object (and the route is been updated).

Why? What am I missing?

When I make `router.push(/foo?page=1)` it works!

Is it a bug ?

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-cache-wg82p?file=/pages/index.js)

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("router.query change", router.query);
  }, [router.query]);

  const changeRoute = () => {
    router.push("/foo", { query: { page: "1" } });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={changeRoute}> change route</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using `router.push` correctly, the second argument where you're passing the query object is meant for the `as` parameter used to decorate the path.

If you want to use the [URL object format](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object) to do the same as `router.push("/foo?page=1")`, then your code should look like the following.

```js
router.push({
    pathname: "/foo",
    query: { page: "1" }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case, it's better to use `getServerSideProps`. You can use the `getServerSideProps` function like this to catch the query params and then do whatever you want.

Also, I would recommend using the `Link` component from Next.js. It's a lot better and provides better accessibility than `router.push`.

```js
import Link from 'next/link';

export const getServerSideProps = async context => {
  const page = context.query.page || 1;
  // Fetch new page or do whatever you want
  const data = await fetch(...);

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      data
    }
  }
}

export default function IndexPage({ page, data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={{ pathname: '/foo', query: { page: '1' } }}>
        <a>
          <button>Change route</button>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This helps the poster, but not the people who showed up here based off the title of the post.